# javascript: How to access object property form inside method with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

```
var test = {
        array: [1,2,3,4],
        events: function() {
            document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", this.show);
        },
        show: function() {
            console.log(this.array);
        }       
}
test.events();
```

This object, when i click a button, addEventListener inside events method will be called and calls the show method. Then show method displays my array, but it only shows undefined. How to fix it?

Comment: Attach on element `<button onclick="test.events()">Click me</button>`

Comment: Because in the listener, *this* is the element, not the *test* object. This is a duplicate, just need to find a good one…

Comment: `document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", this.show.bind(this));`
This will solve the issue

Comment: And [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your issue is that `this` actually behaves differently than what you would expect. When the click event handler (i.e. `this.show`) is executed, the value that is bound to `this` is not the `test` object anymore. I can't explain it better than this [very good chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) from Kyle Simpson's **You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes`**.

In your specific case, you would have to make sure that the value bound to `this` is explicitly set to the `test` object. You can do so in multiple ways:

1. Wrap it inside another function and explicitly call the actual callback function:

   ```
   element.addEventListener('click', () => this.show());
   ```
2. Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicitly bind the `this` value:

   ```
   element.addEventListener('click', this.show.bind(this) );
   ```

Comment: This question is pretty clearly a duplicate (if you've been on StackOverflow a while…) so you should mark it as such rather than answering. Sometimes it's tempting to just post an answer because it's quicker than looking for a good dupe, but it just scatters answers across more questions.

Comment: @RobG I agree, I apologize for that. I will keep this in mind the next time I answer a question in SO. Thank you for calling it out :)